# What is the difference between "comprehend" and "understand"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

What is the difference between the verbs *comprehend* and *understand*?

Can we say

> comprehend a lesson

?

Comment: "to comprehend" is the Latin variant of the normal word "to understand". "to comprehend" is written elevated style.

Comment: Welcome to [ELU.SE] @Hanaa. 
Share your research: show what you've found already, and explain what it is you don't understand.

Comment: "comprehend" is from French. Question answered here: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/192625/whats-the-difference-between-understand-and-comprehend

Answer (score 6):

According to the dictionary, *comprehend* simply means *understand,* but to me the connotations are slightly different.  *Comprehend* seems more "comprehensive" --I would describe it as a deeper and more complete level of understanding.

I also see *comprehend* as dealing more with ability, the mental capacity to grasp something.  For instance, I would say "I *understand* French, I *comprehend* physics."  In terms of French, I either know what the words mean or I don't, it's (arguably) not a conceptual leap.  For physics, I actually need to see the world in a different way.

You might say that a child comprehends a lesson, but only if it represents an actual conceptual advance, not just memorization.

Comment: There is a wealth of nuance in the etymology of understand & comprehend, especially when you compare the two completely different word pictures the words evoke. Seize the opportunity!

Comment: @Hanaa Did you understand the difference, or comprehend it?

Comment: I comprehended it .

Answer (score 2):

You can.....

> Comprehend is a verb that originates from the Latin word
>   comprehendere, which means “catch or seize.”

- When an idea is clear to you and you understand it completely, you [comprehend](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/comprehend) it.
- to take in or embrace; include; comprise.

> .....Education is to help students *understand* the how's and why's. All
>   complicated subjects need you to practice and think. *Understanding requires knowledge and thought.*

- Another kind of understanding is like sympathy. For example,
  you might not approve of stealing, but you could **understand** why a guy
  would steal to feed his family.

Comment: Thanks for the Latin etymology.  I'm reminded of the Biblical "the light shone in the darkness, and the darkness did not *comprehend* it," (John 1:5) where the term seemingly has connotations of *understand*, *accept* and *overcome.*

Answer (score 1):

I would say that they're more or less the same, however used in different contexts.

> I comprehended a lesson

doesn't quite make sense for me; I would say that the differences are solely contextual.

> I understood the lesson

Makes sense to me

However, **note** that it depends on what you mean by lesson: if you're talking about a lesson as in *school*, this would make sense, however if you are speaking of a lesson as in `he's learned his lesson` this wouldn't be appropriate.

Comment: I would say that one can *comprehend* a subject, but *understand* a lesson.

Comment: Yes exactly as you said Matt Gutting

Comment: Yes, exactly @MattGutting